# Upgrade local version of WordPress - links point to live site

Tags: upgrade

I've got my local development version of WordPress and I'd like to upgrade the installation. However, the `WordPress 4.0 is available! Please update now.` link points to the Live site.

All the settings in the `wp-config.php` file and `wp_options` table point to the local site. The database was originally taken from the Live site and the `wp_options` table updated. However there's clearly somewhere that still links to the Live site.

Any ideas where this might be?

Comment: I just dumped my wordpress db and found my site name in lots of places. Have you checked wp_postmeta? If not, try doing a dump and grep.

Comment: Use this bad boy to do search and replaces on your db, absolute site urls are stored ALL OVER THE PLACE in WordPress: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Answer (score 0):

I would do a search of your database for the live site URL. If you are using phpmyadmin then that would be really easy to do. It has to be in your database somewhere for it to be linking there.